# replacement of get_data and set_data in pygtk3

Tags: gtk3, pygtk, pygobject

In `pygtk3`, when using `set_data`, it complained `RuntimeError: Data access methods are unsupported. Use normal Python attributes instead`. In `pygtk`, I can use `set_data` to attach a widget to another widget and use `get_data` to retrieve the attached widget and do something. In `pygtk3`, how can I achieve it?

I couldn't provide a small code. A scenario is, for example, there is an entry and button. When clicking the button, set 'balabala' to the entry.

```py
entry = Gtk.Entry.new()
button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Foo")
button.set_data('qqaa', entry) # In pygtk. How to do it in pygtk3?
button.connect("clicked", on_clicked)

def on_clicked(button):
     entry = button.get_data('qqaa') # In pygtk. How to do it in pygtk3?
     entry.set_text('balabala')
```

**Edit:**
The solution is to use [connect](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/GObject-2.0/classes/Object.html#GObject.Object.connect).The key point is that we can pass more than one parameter.

```py
def master_building_entry_changed(menu, master_building_id, AirBuildr_html_entry):
    idx = menu.get_active()
    if idx != master_building_id:
        master_building_id = idx
        print(master_building_id)
...
master_building_entry = make_menu(MASTER_BUILDING, master_building_id)
# I passed 2 parameters: master_building_id - an int and AirBuildr_html_entry - a Gtk,Entry
master_building_entry.connect("changed", master_building_entry_changed, master_building_id, AirBuildr_html_entry)
...
```